# Dynamically set id for hidden fields in template file

Tags: javascript, smarty

How can I dynamically set id for hidden fields in template file?? I want to display the value in the alert box later using JS.

**Template file**:

```
<table>
%for doc in docs:
<tr>
<td>
<a href = '' onclick="popup1();">Link</a>   
<input type=hidden id="**do something here**" name="hidden" value="{{doc["Field"]}}" />
</td>
</tr>
%end
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
function popup1()
{
alert(document.getElementById("hiddenFieldID").value);
}
```

Can anybody suggest me what to do in **do something here** ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you do not need the ID

If you do

```
<a href="" onclick="return popup1(this);">Link</a>
```

you can have

```
function popup1(anchor) {
  alert(anchor.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
  return false;
}
```

In jQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="popup">Link</a>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $(".popup").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).next().val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Works absolutely fine..! Thank you so much :) @mplungjan